# Expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, Query>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to create a middleware for validating the input data in request.

```
export function validator(schema: Joi.ObjectSchema, key: string) {
  return function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
    try {
      Joi.assert(req[key], schema);
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  };
}
```

But the `req[key]` is throwing following error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Request'.
>     No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Request'.

The other solutions that I found to problems similar to this include the interface in their own code. I don't understand why this error is coming and how to solve this?

Also the following code is from the `express`'s type definition file.

```
interface Request<P extends core.Params = core.ParamsDictionary, ResBody = any, ReqBody = any, ReqQuery = core.Query> extends core.Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery> { }
```

What does the above definition mean?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `key: string` in the definition of `validator` to `key: keyof Request` worked.